# Characteristic function of a non-negative random variable?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Is it possible to decide if a random variable is non-negative almost surely, by looking at the characteristic function of the random variable?

Comment: Since the characteristic function of a random variable completely defines the random variable, the answer, in theory, must be yes...

Comment: Okay, but are you aware about how it can be done?I have a characteristic function and I need to decide if the underlying random variable is positive almost surely?

Comment: You are strangely secretive about this. If your question would be longer than 2 lines, more answers would appear, but right now, your question can simply be answered "yes". Maybe explain what you are doing, what your variable is (well, its char. function) and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:
According to a [theorem (Gil-Pelaez)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas), if $0$ is a point of continuity of $F_X$, then
$$
F_X(0) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{Im}[\phi_X(t)]}{t} dt,
$$
so, since a random variable $X$ is a.s. non-negative, then $F_X(0) = 0$, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{Im}[\phi_X(t)]}{t} dt = \pi / 2$ is the condition for a.s. non-negativity in that case.

$F_X$'s continuity at $0$ can be tested by checking if
$$
\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 T} \int_{-T}^{+T} \phi_X(t) dt = 0.
$$